# Query to return results with maximum date

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a date field in my table. I need to write a query that returns row with maximum date. Means from following dataset, I need all the rows with `20210115`

```
20210115
20210115
20210115
20210115
20210115
20210115
20210115
20210115
20210113
20210113
20210113
20210113
```

I have written following query which gives me correct result but it is very slow.

```
SELECT
    (c.supplementDate)
FROM
    cars AS c 
WHERE
        DATE(c.supplementDate) = (
    SELECT
        MAX(
        DATE( supplementDate )) AS supplementDate 
    FROM
        cars
```

Can anybody suggest me if there is any way without using subquery to get the result ?

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  (That does not look like a `DATE`.)

Comment: Yes that a date .

Comment: In that case simply use the column name, not `DATE()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a `MAX` subquery here:

```sql
SELECT supplementDate
FROM cars
WHERE supplementDate = (SELECT MAX(supplementDate) FROM cars);
```

With the advent of MySQL 8+, we can also use the `RANK` analytic function:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT supplementDate, RANK() OVER (ORDER BY supplementDate DESC) rnk
    FROM cars
)

SELECT supplementDate
FROM cte
WHERE rnk = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

I anticipate that your date is in string format so I have used casting for that.Here is you code please check =>

```
SELECT * FROM MYTable WHERE 
CAST(MyDate AS DATE)=
(Select  MAX(CAST(MyDate AS DATE)) from MYTable);
```

**Note:** [DB-Fiddle LINK](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hKe97RZ6g7fLxwEjikYPke/2).

Comment: Casting does nothing useful here

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to convert the value to a date, so this is sufficient:

```
SELECT c.*
FROM cars c 
WHERE c.supplementDate = (SELECT MAX(c2.supplementDate) FROM cars c2);
```

To speed this query, you want an index on `cars(supplementDate)`:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_cars_supplementDate ON cars(supplementDate);
```

Note that even if you have the index but still use `DATE()`, then the query will not use the index.  Functions tend to inhibit the optimizer and index usage.